# Download manager that can open magnet links from file or clipboard?

Tags: download-manager, bittorrent

In general, download managers allow you to add HTTP or FTP links to the files you want to download.

For example in JDownloader2 or in uGet, I can open a list of links like this one:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Amstel.jpg
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Atisha.jpg
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carcar.jpg
```

I can add those links by telling the download manager to grab the links from the clipboard or from a text file.

The problem that I have is that I have a file containing magnet links and I can't find a way to add those links to uTorrent.

my urls.txt file looks like this:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:D540FC48EB12F2833163EED6421D449DD8F1CE1F&dn=Ubuntu+desktop+19.04+%2864bit%29&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker..
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5CDF31EDA177B6E1017634A3D9CB3B02F1C5E8D2&dn=LibreOffice+6.3.2+Windows+x64&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker..
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:0EACBBB2ADB0D33DCE98670378559A339DA2BA11&dn=Netbeans+7.0+Full+Windows+English&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transmission` plus `Transmission Remote GUI` by copy in clipboard the content of file and start `Transmission Remote GUI`. The only disadvantage is you need to click OK/confirm for any of the downloads.

Comment: I just tried it and it works. It is still a big improvement - I don't have to click on every magnet link in order to start downloading each file

Comment: I found the solution for getting rid of the prompt:  Tools --> Application Options and then uncheck: Prompt for download options when adding new torrents